# Answering a phone call

Tags: calls

When someone calls me I can't see the call screen but I can feel the vibration and I hear my ringtone. But the screen is total black. I have to push the lock button to wake up the screen. How can I fix it?

Comment: Which phone and Android version would it be?

Comment: What phonebhave you got and optional what ROM and version?

Answer (score -1):

First go to Settings -> Apps and check if you have disable the Dialer or Phone app. If so please enable it and then check after restarting your phone.

If your Phone/Dialer app is not disabled then try these steps,

- Settings -> Apps -> All(Tab) -> Dialer
- Clear Cache and Clear Data
- Disable it, restart phone and re-enable the Dialer app.